# Is it possible that I can change Port Number in Oracle 10g for remote connections

Tags: oracle

I am creating a project in Oracle
Is it possible that I can change Port Number in Oracle 10g for remote connections ?

Answer (score 3):

This is more an administration than a coding question:

Oracle connections are based on server-side "listeners" - these can be configured independently of the DB itself and can use any IP/port...

[Click here to read how to do that exactly - BTW: it depends on your server+network config (i.e. which OS ? Is the DB on a RAC ? etc.)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B13789_01/network.101/b10775/listenercfg.htm)!

Basically you just need to setup a listener for the DB/instance with the port number you want server-side and then use that in your client-side connection-string / TNSNAMES-config.

Answer (score 0):

For temporary use you can also use Linux iptables NAT Redirect